# ToolBar android with different buttons

Tags: android, toolbar

I need to create a toolbar that has BACK BUTTON in all screens except in the main screen.

Also, i need that the toolbar has differents buttons depending on the screen.

Is this possible?

Is toolbar the good solution?

Thanks.

Comment: U can set ur toolbar as setSupportActionBar(toolbar) and add menu items using onCreateOptionMenu .

Comment: I'm personally not a fan of ActionBar/Toolbar.  Their API is ugly and restrictive.  I'd suggest creating a custom compound View which you then have full control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create your custom toolbar:**

```
toolbar.xml
```

**Include this in the activity layout you want using:**

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar"
    ></include>
```

**Initialize your toolbar in the Activity code :**

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
```

**To get the BACK BUTTON in screens you can write :**

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**To add more option in toolbar create your own custom menu file in the menu resource directory of your res directory.**

eg :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_settings"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    </menu>
```

**Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to Inflate the menu and Handle the item clicks.**

Answer (score 0):

If your activity is extending [AppCompatActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) there is a [method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#setSupportActionBar(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)) for setting the toolbar to act as ActionBar, don't forget to check the style theme you applied to the app is proper, then you apply the menus ( xml resource), to toolbar object.

**Note**: toolbar should be in the current activity layout.